# BeautifulSoup 4 - How to replace anchor tag with it's text

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have html content in my document. I need to replace all the anchor tags with their respective texts using `BeautifulSoup`.

My input is

```
html = '''They are also much more fuel-efficient than <a href="http://someurl.com">rockets</a>.'''
```

Expected output

```
"They are also much more fuel-efficient than rockets."
```

Here is my code

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for a in soup.find_all('a'):
    ...
    replacement_string = a.string
    //I get all the anchor tags here. I need to perform the replace operation here
    ...
//Should display 'They are also much more fuel-efficient than rockets.'
print(replaced_html_string)
```

I was able to replace the elements of the anchor tag but not the whole tag itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need to separate all the tags out to get the text. just use `.text`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.text)
```

gives:

```
'They are also much more fuel-efficient than rockets.'
```

---

Or in your way:

```
res = str(soup)
for i in soup.find_all('a'):
    res = res.replace(str(i),i.text)
```